# Bug with dropdown background in Bootstrap 4 alpha-5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to work out what is going on here. Please see the attached fiddle:

http://www.bootply.com/FoVksRcRLf

If you look at it in Chrome/Safari, and you should see the issue:

[image]

IE Edge and Firefox show it correctly.

[image]

I've looked in Firebug / Developer tools, and I just can't figure out where the gradient is coming from!

There also seems to be a couple of px margin being added into it (if you hover over "Directory", you will see the orange background goes all the way to the top of the bar - but this is not the case on the "Owners" dropdown)

I'm open to suggestions, as this is driving me up the wall :/

Comment: its from `html [type=button] {  -webkit-appearance: button; }`, you can try remove `type=button` from `a` tag.

Comment: @tmg - OMG, you legend! That was it! Any ideas on the extra margin at the top of it? Its bearable now, but still looks like a 2 or 3px margin on it

Comment: that might be your custom style: `nav #dropdownMenuButton {  padding: 0px 10px; }`, try remove that

Comment: @tmg - you star... that was it! I put that in to try and correct the other issue, but forgot to take it out. Please add your answer, and I will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is coming from `html [type=button] { -webkit-appearance: button; }`.
Remove attribute `type=buttom` from `a` tag.

From [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-type)

> The type attribute, if present, gives the MIME type of the linked
>   resource. It is purely advisory. The value must be a valid MIME type.

So `button` is not even a proper value for `type` attribute of anchor element.

Comment: Thanks tmg. Funnily enough, the code came from the official BS docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns , but their example was for a `<button>` . I guess I must have changed it to an `<a>` tag, and forgotten to remove that part :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby for `<button>` `type=button` is valid. The second example, that uses `<a>` tag, type attribute is not present.

Comment: yeah I know, thats what I was saying (it must have been copied over when I changed from a `<button>` to `<a>` :))